# How to make such dictionary in setting bundle

Tags: ios, xcode5, settings.bundle

I'm trying to add a dictionary inside my setting bundle the one where i can show my icon and Application name just like the one which is shown in Facebook, Vimeo, etc. application how should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.sivamuthukumar.net/2013/05/custom-settings-bundle-to-ios-app.html) and [Apples document](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)

[This](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1846575&seqNum=12) and [this](http://www.ecanarys.com/blog-entry/implementing-ios-setting-bundle) has a nice discussion about setting bundle. Sorry I can not give a direct answer but once I got some help from these links. Do some reading and you will get your answer.

Comment: But both links don't answer my question could you please tell me which dictionary should i use?